# Import from *.txt to DataGridView without 2 columns

Tags: c#, datagridview

Sorry for my English. I'm newbie in c#. I have quuestion. I have file txt with data:

```
 20160101    PL01    000000000000000003    PL02    TO    0000000001           1.720        0000000001    0000000002
```

Finnaly i want import this data to DataGridView but only columns 1,4,7,8,9 without columns 2,3,5 and 6.

I try on start Import all data but I have error

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication10
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("C:\\Users\\terrazo\\Desktop\\test1.txt");
            string[] columnnames = file.ReadLine().Split(' ');
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            foreach (string c in columnnames)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(c);
            }
            string newline;
            while ((newline = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                string[] values = newline.Split(' ');
                for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                {
                    dr[i] = values[i];
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
            file.Close();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me how import data from txt file without several columns??
thx for all answer.

Comment: "***I try on start Import all data but I have error***", well what is it

Comment: When I start i have error messege: An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Can't find column 8.

Comment: Does your data have a space in it?

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through your code and also the error you are facing and came to know that your text file while taken in account also have null spaces or multiple blank space and when you are split it on whitespace base it will also have some null values. I have updated your code for the same please try it and in case you face some problem please feel free to ask me.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication10
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("C:\\Users\\terrazo\\Desktop\\test1.txt");
        string[] columnnames = file.ReadLine().Split(' ');
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        foreach (string c in columnnames)
        {
            if (c != "")
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(c);
            }
        }
        string newline;
        while ((newline = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            string[] values = newline.Split(' ');
            for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
            {
                if (values[i] != "")
                {
                    dr[i] = values[i];
                }
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        file.Close();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: @terrazo Please mark it as answered if you find it useful so it will help others too.